C++ Struct with char* losing value when returned?
I'm new to C++ and I can't figure out why my code is losing the value for username and password.
Client *client = new Client();

char *authBuffer = new char[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE]; // buffer contains 234567|john|pwd4john

bufferToClient(authBuffer, client);

printf("id=%i username=%s password=%s\n", client->id, client->username, client->password);

// output is: id=234567 username= password=

// function 

void bufferToClient(char *buffer, Client *client) {
    
    memset(client, 0x00, CLIENT_STRUCT_SIZE);
    
    char *token = strtok(buffer, PIPE); // pipe |
    
    client->id = atoi(token);
    client->username = strtok(0, PIPE);
    client->password = strtok(0, PIPE);
    
    printf("%i\n", client->id);
    printf("%s\n", client->username);
    printf("%s\n", client->password);

    // everything is ok and prints out the values as expected

    // 234567
    // john
    // pwd4john

    delete token;
}

// struct

struct Client {

    unsigned int id;
    const char *username;
    const char *password;

    virtual ~Client() {

        delete username;
        delete password;
    }
};

static const int CLIENT_STRUCT_SIZE = sizeof(Client);

I'm sure it must be something simple but I just can't figure out why it keeps dropping the values for username and password. At one point I had username coming back ok but password was all messed up.
One of the things I tried was:
client->username = std::string(token).c_str();
client->password = std::string(token).c_str();

output: client id=234567 username=john password=    ²
But as you can see username is good but password is messed up?
Update... to deal with dangling pointers I took this approach?
void bufferToClient(char *buffer, Client *client) {

    memset(client, 0x00, CLIENT_STRUCT_SIZE);

    char *token, *tokenPtr;

    tokenPtr = token = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];

    token = strtok(buffer, PIPE);

    client->id = atoi(token);
    client->username = strtok(0, PIPE);
    client->password = strtok(0, PIPE);

    delete[] tokenPtr;
}

Update: It appears to be working now. To be honest I'm not sure what made it start working and I don't want to backtrack to find out. What I did do was removed the std::strings().c_str() conversions... then I added a pointer to the original pointer (so I can do what I'm hoping is a correct delete[] on the strtok pointer) since strtok moves the pointer along as someone explained in the comments. Then I removed the virtual destructor (as someone mentioned it may cause memset copy issues) from the struct and put deletes on username and password. And I found a bug where I was printf'n a variable but forgot to put the variable in the print statement which threw me off because a value was printed that was similar to what I was expecting but incorrect. I think it was the std::strings().c_str() conversions though cause once I got rid of them username and password were being returned correctly.
FYI this is 15+ yr old code that I'm doing a few enhancements to... that's why it's not the latest C++ style... but for old code it's incredibly fast compared to the same code in Java21. Like comparing a Bugatti to a 1980's Honda Civic... haha. I guess "the lower you go the faster you go".

This code does not compile.  It's missing stuff.  A [mcve] would be helpful.  The code should not use new or delete; C++ has better constructs to use, like std::string (a specialized smart pointer dealing with strings and the memory management thereof).

@Eljay I think learning to understand new/delete and raw pointer stuff is useful as a new C/C++ programmer; you have to understand what a std::string is doing under the hood to use it well.

Have you read how std::strtok works? It returns pointer to the original buffer after inserting a \0 in place of first delimiter found. Since you store these pointers in your class and then delete the buffer, you have dangling pointers. Or not even that, since you used wrong delete to destroy the buffer, it's hard to say what happens.

memset on a non-trivially copyable type is wrong. If you are writing C++ instead of C there should be almost no reason to use memset at all. The correct syntax for clearing the object is *client = {};. There is no need for CLIENT_STRUCT_SIZE either and you just risk making it a wrong value. If you insist on using memset, then it should at least be sizeof(*client) instead, so that there can't be any accidental size mismatch.

In general, it looks like you learned a bit of C and a bit of C++ and now you have a mix of the two languages. That's a bad idea. Consider them completely distinct languages and only consider their intersection when you need to write interfaces to C libraries. Otherwise you will cause all kinds of undefined behavior if you aren't very aware of the differences. For example there is no way that delete on a pointer provided by a C standard library function (even if that pointer was dynamically allocated) could ever be correct, because C functions would allocate with e.g. malloc, not new.

@Kaia At some point, yes, but I strongly agree with Kate Gregory here - pointers should be considered highly advanced feature of the language. A person that is "new to C++" should not see any asterisk expect for multiplication.

@user17732522 Oddly enough, *token isn't a malloc'd pointer, it's a pointer into authBuffer, which is allocated with new[]. (Which is more evidence for not mixing C and C++)

You are also ignoring important C++ rules like the rule-of-0/3/5 for Client. That's probably the most important thing to get right when writing C++. Similarly you are trying to deallocate something allocated by new[] with delete instead of delete[] which also causes undefined behavior, etc.

Btw. because your destructor in Client is virtual, my issue with memset isn't only a theoretical one. It will actually cause the program to fail with a null pointer dereference in practice. A type with virtual destructor is never trivially-copyable and so memset/memcpy can't be used.

I wouldn't go so far as to call pointers "highly advanced." I taught them alongside vectors and arrays in Intro. I consider pointers the "parallel parking" of C++; scarier than they are. If we're going to avoid them altogether, might as well pick another language. I will note that I never taught to prefer them. Students were expected to use vectors and Standard Library strings. But C++ was kept as the language for Intro because the idea was to build a foundation for a 4 year degree, not a 12 week boot camp.

@Yksisarvinen hmm, I'll watch the video in a bit. I think I might just be old-fashioned, but it feels to me like C++ is a language made of footguns that only make any sense if you have a vague idea of what's going on at the asm/memory level, and I'd much rather have a dev who's shot themselves in the foot enough times to know it hurts! If someone says "a string is a smart pointer" you still ultimately need to know what happens if you do std::string myStr(otherStr); -- in which situations does it copy and in which situations is it sharing a pointer to the same memory etc

@sweenish I would say pointers live at a lower abstraction level. And maybe 40 years ago the teaching style was bottom up. That start work at the CPU level and work up to abstract languages like assembly and "C").  I really value a more top-down approach, start at the higher abstraction level (in which less mistakes can be made) and work your way down (when really needed, like creating high performance datastructures of your own). So start by learning correct use of C++ and the standard library first.

On footguns, I'm in agreement with Stroustrup: C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off

If you're going to use char arrays instead of std::string and make them members of a class/struct, then you better read up on the rule of three/five/zero.

This question is similar to: Freeing memory after calling strtok() causes an error. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks alot for all the input... I really appreciate your time to answer and share your thoughts. I inherited this code to maintain and it feels extremely fast compared to the same code written in Java.

@defa0009 -- That entire bufferToClient function can be written using std::getline and std::istringstream, all without messing around with the original buffer and using strtok.  See this.

@PaulMcKenzie -- thanks Paul I'll definitely give that a try and will eventually start porting the code over to be more modern like you suggested. I still want to understand why using std::string sets username ok but password comes back messed up?

Why all the manual memory management? In modern C++ you hardly ever need manual new/delete.

Get rid of the strtok. It's the first step you should take. It's considered a forbidden function in C++. It will also be removed from the standard in the near future

std::strtok does not allocate memory, it modifies the buffer in-place and then returns pointers into the buffer.
Here's a subset of your code:
char *authBuffer = new char[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
// Fill authBuffer with "234567|john|pwd4john\00" somewhere

char *token = strtok(buffer, PIPE);
client->username = strtok(0, PIPE);
delete token;
printf("id=%i username=%s password=%s\n", ...);

Say authBuffer points to the memory address 0x8000000. Right before delete token;, here's what our buffer and the pointers pointing to it look like.
2 3 4 5 6 7 \00 j o h n \00 p w d 4 j o h n \00

^- authBuffer: 0x8000000
^--- token: 0x8000000
                ^- client->username: 0x8000007
                            ^- client->password: 0x800000c

Then, we execute delete token, which frees the memory we allocated at memory 0x8000000. The memory management system doesn't know how long token is, it just knows that the buffer it allocated at 0x8000000 is MAX_BUFFER_SIZE chars long, and it deletes that, which means all of your pointers are invalid, and the memory they point to could change to anything without warning. Right now, it seems that they're getting set to null bytes, but that memory address could also be reallocated later in your program, and those pointers would let the user read or write whatever they want in that memory. (a "use-after-free")
(As a sidenote, when you use new[], you need to also use delete[]. Using delete might work in some cases, but it can fail in catastrophic ways if you aren't careful.)
The fix:

Copy your tokens into their own buffers or std::strings before you deallocate authBuffer.
Consider using std::string to avoid having to do memory management yourself. Generally, only use new/delete/pointers when you really need to.
Use a tool like valgrind (or your IDE may have builtin support for something similar) to automatically detect memory leaks or heap corruption issues in the future.


Thanks for the nice reply it helped. I did try putting them in std:strings before and got the username ok but not the password and thats what I can't figure out?

@defa0009 -- Are you still using printf to output the text?  If you are, did you change it to printf("%s\n", client->username.c_str()); and printf("%s\n", client->password.c_str());?  If you are using std::cout instead of printf, then you wouldn't need to use c_str().  This is yet another reason to reduce if not eliminate, the C-isms in your code (i.e. not use printf).

@PaulMcKenzie -- thanks Paul., yes I had already did a c string on the username and password before printf'n them. The code is 15yrs old with no couts anywhere... I'm just maintaining it with a few enhancements here and there until we decide to rebuild it into the latest C++ version.
